# Validations not working on page submit of oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I know that all validations get executed on Page Submit, but i have actions defined on page submit which i want to be executed first followed by the validations, ie decide the execution options for these dynamic actions to be executed first and then the validations, because right now my validations don't seem to work.My dynamic actions are defined in function and global declaration as   $("#submit").click( function (){ })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't override events in Javascript. I forget, but you may interfere with how Apex handles them. What you want to do is:

1. Set your button's action to be Defined By Dynamic Action
2. Create a Click Dynamic Action on your button
3. Add a True event for whatever it is you're trying to do
4. Your final True event should be Submit, with an appropriate Request value

If your Validations are not executing correctly, turn on debugging mode and look in the debug log for why they're not working.